# Textbox value appending in query string using pushState clips off after space

Tags: javascript

I am trying to append query string with the value entered in a textbox using pushState in JavaScript. Though the value appends in the query string as we type in the textbox but there is one issue.

If the value in the textbox has a space then this value clips off in the query string. So If I type in "javascript test" then only "javascript" appends in the query string and remaining text is clipped off. Moreover, in this case, even the backspace key doesn't fire my keyup event and the value doesn't remove from the query string. How can we fix this issue?

```js
$("#plan").keyup(function(){
  var key = $(this).data("key");
  var value = $(this).val();
  addQueryString(key, value);
});


function addQueryString(key, value)
{
  var searchUrl = location.search;

  if(searchUrl.indexOf("?") == "-1")
  {
    var urlValue = '?'+key+'='+value;
    history.pushState({state: 1, rand: Math.random()}, '', urlValue);
  }
  else
  {
    if(searchUrl.indexOf(key) == "-1")
    {
      var urlValue = searchUrl+'&'+key+'='+value;
    }
    else
    {
      oldValue = getParameterByName(key);
      if(searchUrl.indexOf("?"+key+"=") != "-1")
      {
        urlValue = searchUrl.replace('?'+key+'='+oldValue, '?'+key+'='+value);
      }
      else
      {
        urlValue = searchUrl.replace('&'+key+'='+oldValue, '&'+key+'='+value);  
      }
    }

    history.pushState({state:1, rand: Math.random()}, '', urlValue);
  }
}

function getParameterByName(name)
{
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="plan" id="plan" value="" data-key="plan" />
```

Comment: I found the issue. It was because of `decodeURIComponent()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the value string using [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

```js
$("#plan").keyup(function() {
  var key = $(this).data("key");
  var value = $(this).val();
  addQueryString(key, value);
});

function addQueryString(key, value) {
  var searchUrl = location.search;
  // Encode the value here
  value = encodeURIComponent(value);
  if (searchUrl.indexOf("?") == "-1") {
    var urlValue = '?' + key + '=' + value;
    history.pushState({
      state: 1,
      rand: Math.random()
    }, '', urlValue);
  } else {
    if (searchUrl.indexOf(key) == "-1") {
      var urlValue = searchUrl + '&' + key + '=' + value;
    } else {
      oldValue = getParameterByName(key);
      if (searchUrl.indexOf("?" + key + "=") != "-1") {
        urlValue = searchUrl.replace('?' + key + '=' + oldValue, '?' + key + '=' + value);
      } else {
        urlValue = searchUrl.replace('&' + key + '=' + oldValue, '&' + key + '=' + value);
      }
    }
    console.log('history.pushState:', urlValue);
    /*
    history.pushState({
      state: 1,
      rand: Math.random()
    }, '', urlValue); 
    */
  }
}

function getParameterByName(name) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
  return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="plan" id="plan" value="" data-key="plan" />
```